# Convert string datetime into Java Long with XStream

Tags: java, xml, datetime, xstream, oxm

I'm trying to get XStream to be able to convert a string that contains a datetime (such as `2013-01-23 16:50:39.495855`) into a `java.lang.Long` instance.

Currently, I have XML like so:

```
<widget>
    <timestamp val="2013-01-23 16:50:39.495855"/>
</widget>
```

I want to convert this into a standard Unix epoch timestamp (number of millis since Jan 1, 1970). Since the above datetime translates into a Unix epoch timestamp of (if my math is right) `1358959839000`, I'd like XStream to convert this into a `new Long(1358959839000)` instance.

I don't believe this is possible with XStream's alias methods, and I would probably need to write my own `Converter`, however a `com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.basic.LongConverter` already exists, so I'm not sure how to write my own `UnixEpochLongConverter` seeing that both converters are attempting to convert a String to a Long. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do this conversion (i.e. Date -> Long) within XStream?

Comment: I have a Java POJO (that I can't change) that has a `Long timestamp` field. I need XStream to convert the XML into an instance of this POJO, so I need to accomplish the conversion with XStream.

Comment: couldn't you use an intermediary object that is then converted to the POJO you're speaking of?

Comment: I guess I could, but I'd like to see if any XStream gurus out there can weigh-in on a converter-based solution, which feels cleaner. But good suggestion, and I'll consider it if XStream truly isn't capable of this kind of conversion.

Comment: XStream is certainly capable of the conversion..

Comment: Thanks @mre - if XStream is capable of this conversion, do you have any idea how to configure it to do so? Can you provide an answer with a code example, or point me to an article that shows using such an intermediary object that you speak of? Thanks again, and +1.

Comment: Sure, but XStream provides its own [Converter Tutorial](http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html) w/ code examples.

Comment: That tutorial doesn't show an example that applies to my current situation. It shows how to write a basic converter, which I already know how to do. I'm trying to figure out how to override the LongConverter that XStream already ships with, since its insufficient for what I need to use it for.

Comment: if it's insufficient, then roll your own as shown in the examples...

Comment: Rolling my own won't change the fact that the `DefaultConverterLookup` will read a string and think that the `LongConverter` is the appropriate converter to use. I need a way to tell it to use a different converter. This is the root of my problem. Once I specify the correct converter to use, I can roll my own and specify that converter.

Comment: And it's not just a simple matter of using the `registerConverter` method, I need to tell XStream to use `LongConverter` in some cases, and my homegrown converter in other cases.

Comment: couldn't you just override the `unmarshal` method of your custom converter, as shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739228/xstream-deserialization-when-variable-type-changed/4890752#4890752)?

Comment: I think we're getting lost in semantics here. With the code that I have, XStream is selecting its own `LongConverter`, which doesn't know how to translate a datetime string (i.e. "2013-01-23 16:50:39.495855") into a Long instance. I need to write my own converter (using the tutorial you have suggested), but that alone isn't enough. This is because XStream is using a `DefaultConverterLookup` which will always tell it to use the `LongConverter` instead of my homegrown converter. I need to tell this `DefaultLookupConverter` to use my homegrown converter when it encounters such a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either register your Custom converter as local using [registerLocalConverter](http://xstream.codehaus.org/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.html#registerLocalConverter%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.Converter%29) or with priority above `XStream.PRIORITY_NORMAL`.

```
xstream.registerLocalConverter(
    Widget.class, 
    "timestamp", 
     new UnixEpochLongConverter());
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the DateFormat object to convert the string to a java.util.Date object and then do date.getTime() to return a long value . Below is an example. You could write a method in your object that basically converts the string to long.

```
 String date = "2013-01-23 16:50:39.495855";
 DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.S");
 Date datem = format.parse(date);
 long longDate = datem.getTime();
 System.out.println(longDate);
```

Comment: Thanks @Zenil, but this only shows me how to convert a String to a long, which wasn't my question. I need to configure XStream to do this when it parses the `date` string as you provided above. Can you provide a more complete code example that shows this code snippet inside an XStream converter, or some other object that overrides XStream's `LongConverter`?

Comment: Saw your POJO comment. If you do consider  a non-xstream solution you could write a static utility method that takes your POJO ,computes the long from your POJO date string and returns it

Comment: Hey, I found this link which gives a nice intro to writing your own converters http://xstream.codehaus.org/converter-tutorial.html .Give it a shot. If you face problems, I could try writing one.